# Unity 8 On screen keyboard

Tags: unity, keyboard, 16.10, accessibility, unity8

When in Unity 8, there is no onscreen keyboard when I am using my Toshiba satellite without my physical keyboard. The touch works perfect but no on screen keyboard. In settings it says: "On-Screen Keyboard" and says zero and when i click on that setting it is just a blank screen. I tried installing onboard through Libertine but that doesnt integrate the input with the Unity 8 desktop sadly. Is there a way to get an onscreen keyboard in the 16.10 Unity 8 preview?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Unity 8 is NOT a supported Desktop Environment- it is still a development build and not supported here.

Comment: Really? Bummer.

Comment: @PatrickNegus if it's not a supported desktop environment, why does it ship on the Ubuntu 16.10 ISO?

This is more likely [bug #1521518](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity8/+bug/1521518).

Comment: @StephenM.Webb It is a beta DE in development, and doesn't even work properly in most systems. I see you are a Unity 8 contributor, and you should know its issues better than I do. As you pointed out, OP's issue is most likely a bug, which *does not belong here*.

Comment: It would be a duplicate of that bug except there is no physical keyboard attached on boot or ever. It isn't docked.

Comment: @kyaustad *something* is being detected as a physical keyboard, that's the trigger to not show the OSK.  It's possible the BIOS of the device reports a keyboard attached regardless of its physical presence so that other systems don't panic at boot.  It's odd, but not unlikely.  Work in Unity 8 is ongoing to support convertible devices that always have a physical keybord but it's not there yet.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try and see if it can be toggled. Thanks for the info everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem on another Bay Trail Tablet, running 17.04 beta. 
You get the keyboard by "apt install ubuntu-keyboard".
More: http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/yakkety/ubuntu-keyboard